# My terminal has stopped sourcing my .profile file

Tags: bash, prompt, profile

I installed `starship` (https://starship.rs/) the other day to make my prompt more useful, and as cool as it is, it broke a number of things about my terminal so I uninstalled it.

Unfortunately, even with it uninstalled it's left some things broken.

Below is a screenshot of iTerm2 showing my prompt with and without my `~/.profile` sourced. Before I installed `starship` I would be given the `matt@prince` prompt automatically and that's what I want to get back to. There's loads of other good stuff (aliases, functions, bash completions, etc.) that I now don't get until manually sourcing my `.profile`.

The same thing happens if I use macOS' `terminal` app too. What can I do to fix it?

[image: screenshot of iTerm2 showing prompt with and without .profile file sourced]

Comment: Please add `ls -ld .bash* .prof*` and its result to your question

Comment: I thought that `zsh` was the default shell on a Mac these days, but you're running `bash`. Is that intended?

Comment: _Adding_ this fancy prompt system involves just appending a one-line `eval` command at the end of `.bashrc`.  What _exactly_ did you do to remove that?

Comment: @Quasímodo yes I have a `PS1=` line in my `.profile`, it's worked for years. I can understand that it might be better in `.bashrc` but why is it important?

Comment: @roaima Yeah, that's intentional. I'll make the switch one day :)

Comment: @JdeBP it's commented out, that's all! The thing is that I think it was something about the installation of `starship` that broke it in the first place, not any changes that I made.

Comment: Consider changing your login shell to [zsh](http://zsh.org/) or [fish](http://fishshell.com/)

Comment: @Matthew I read in the bash manual that `.profile` will only be sourced by login shells. But if it works for you on non-login shells, I am missing some detail there...

Answer (score 1):

Roaima, you were onto something..

```
matt@prince ~ $ ls -ld .bash* .prof*
-rw-------  1 matt  staff  18699 12 May 20:29 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--  1 matt  staff     98 10 May 23:02 .bash_profile
drwx------  9 matt  staff    288 12 May 12:59 .bash_sessions
-rw-r--r--  1 matt  staff   3148 10 May 23:04 .profile
```

The presence of `.bash_profile` meant that `.profile` wasn't being loaded.

I renamed `.bash_profile` to `.bash_profile.bak` and everything started working again. I don't have anything in my `.bash_profile`, other than some stuff to try to get `starship` working.

Thanks @Roaima!

Comment: Pleased i was able to help